# Using rowspan tag in table rendered with Virtualize component

Tags: html-table, blazor, html-rendering

Im struggling with setting a `rowspan` in a table rendered using  component. It seems that for every rendered view I need to build a custom table scaffolding in order to get proper rowspan.

```
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <Virtualize Items="@Models" Context="model">
        <tr>
           <th rowspan="??">label of several rows<th>
           <td>model data in cell</td>
           <td>model data in cell</td>
           ...
           <td>model data in cell</td>
        </tr>
      </Virtualize>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    </table>
```

Where "??" is a non-constant value.

The only solution I see is to get the currently rendered part of the list in the  component. Is there a way to get such data?

Take a look at the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpLbexa7/1/). If the Virtualize component renders only rows between 2 and 7, the table is left without the first row `rowspan` tag and hance it is broken like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpLbexa7/2/).

Comment: Please add your Blazor code generating the tables.

Comment: I am surprised it works. The virtualize component will add a `div` before and after the rendered rows to maintain the height for the scroll bar. This will break the `table` element.

Comment: How do expect `rowspan` to work.  Virtualize's context is based on rows, it's like expecting a 2D model to understand a third dimension!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis not necessarily. If you’d have access to rendered part of the list, you could recalculate rowspans for each render.

Comment: If you're in control of the loop agreed, though there's still some tricky coding.  However, with Virtualize I don't think you are, hence my comment.